# Surface charge at the boundary between two dielectric

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, dielectric

> A point charge q sits at z = −d on the z-axis. Find the polarization
> charge density $σ_P$ induced on the plane z = 0 when the half-space z > 0 is filled with a medium with dielectric constant $K_R$ and the half-space z < 0 is filled with a medium with dielectric
> constant $K_L$.

$$\sigma_P = (P_2-P_1).\hat z = (\epsilon_0 (K_2-1) E_2-\epsilon_0 (K_1-1) E_1).\hat z$$

But, we have that $K_L E_L . \hat n = K_R E_R . \hat n$, and we also have:

$$E_L = E_o/K_L, E_R = E_o/K_R (3)$$

$$\sigma_P = (\epsilon_0 (K_L-1) E_o/K_L-\epsilon_0 (K_R-1) E_o/K_R).\hat z $$
$$\sigma_P = (- \epsilon_0 E_o/K_L+\epsilon_0 E_o/K_R).\hat z = \epsilon_o E_o (1/K_r - 1/K_L).\hat z$$

But this answer is wrong.

I am not sure why, or in another words, which consideration i have assumed that was wrong.

I am pretty sure my first equation is right. So is my second equation, what bothers me is that maybe (3) is wrong, but isn't this just a well know equation? I mean, $E = D/\epsilon = E_o/k$

So what is the problem?

Also, i should say i know how to got the answer by another method. So please does not just post a solution here, but instead i would like you just point it to me me in which point did i have commited a mistake.

Comment: What is $E_0 $?

Comment: @Puk E on vacuum

Comment: In general $E_L = E_0/K_L$ and $E_R = E_0/K_R$ aren't valid. You can't just replace all media with vacuum, calculate the vacuum field and then use a proportionality factor to get the actual E-field.